# What does the two-point correlator of the energy-momentum tensor mean (clarification)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, correlation-functions

I had a final project in a QFT 2 course on c-theorems in QFT where quantities such as $\langle T_{zz}(x)T_{zz}(0)\rangle$ where $T_{zz}$ is the energy-momentum tensor in holomorphic coordinates, was common to see and utilize, **but** I never thought about why or what these correlators are actually saying or doing. For example, to actually do this calculation, I would need to specify a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ in $d=2$, find the energy-momentum tensor, and then use the operator version in terms of $a$'s for the fields. But, what does that tell me?

For example, I could compute for any set of coordinates in $d=2$,
\begin{equation}
\langle T_{\mu\nu}(x)T_{\rho\sigma}(0)\rangle \sim \int d\mu \rho(\mu)\int\frac{d^2p}{(2\pi)^2}e^{ipx}\frac{\left(g_{\mu\nu}p^2 - p_\mu p_\nu\right)\left(g_{\sigma\rho}p^2 - p_\rho p_\sigma\right)}{p^2 + \mu^2},
\end{equation}
for some mass scale $\mu$ (this is for a free scalar). But, I have no idea what this means physically.

I could think of this as two currents coming together and what their probability is of creating a specific particle, but I feel that is completely off.

(Note: I believe the example I did above is correct, but how to compute the two-point function of **any** energy-momentum tensor is a bit hazy to me, so if anyone has any insight or resources that would be helpful).

Any sort of help is of course appreciated.